# Why is this code not deterministic?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

The following snippet is code from **water-nsq** benchmark from **SPLASH 2**...

```
    if (comp_last > NMOL1) 
    {
        for (mol = StartMol[ProcID]; mol < NMOL; mol++) 
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&gl->MolLock[mol % MAXLCKS]);

            for ( dir = XDIR; dir  <= ZDIR; dir++) {
                temp_p = VAR[mol].F[DEST][dir];
                temp_p[H1] += PFORCES[ProcID][mol][dir][H1];
                temp_p[O]  += PFORCES[ProcID][mol][dir][O];
                temp_p[H2] += PFORCES[ProcID][mol][dir][H2];
            }

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&gl->MolLock[mol % MAXLCKS]);
        }

        comp = comp_last % NMOL;
        for (mol = 0; ((mol <= comp) && (mol < StartMol[ProcID])); mol++) 
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&gl->MolLock[mol % MAXLCKS]);

            for ( dir = XDIR; dir  <= ZDIR; dir++) 
            {
                temp_p = VAR[mol].F[DEST][dir];
                temp_p[H1] += PFORCES[ProcID][mol][dir][H1];
                temp_p[O]  += PFORCES[ProcID][mol][dir][O];
                temp_p[H2] += PFORCES[ProcID][mol][dir][H2];
            }

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&gl->MolLock[mol % MAXLCKS]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (mol = StartMol[ProcID]; mol <= comp_last; mol++) 
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&gl->MolLock[mol % MAXLCKS]);

            for ( dir = XDIR; dir  <= ZDIR; dir++) 
            {
                temp_p = VAR[mol].F[DEST][dir];
                temp_p[H1] += PFORCES[ProcID][mol][dir][H1];
                temp_p[O]  += PFORCES[ProcID][mol][dir][O];
                temp_p[H2] += PFORCES[ProcID][mol][dir][H2];
            }

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&gl->MolLock[mol % MAXLCKS]);
        } 
    }

    pthread_barrier_wait(&(gl->start));
```

The problem is that it is not deterministic at the barrier in the end, that is, if you execute this code two times with same inputs, it gives different answers. In other words, if the lock order of mutexes is changed, the results are different.

And yes I have verified this by noting the memory pages. Also I can assure you that the change occurs in the **VAR**'s (pointed by **temp_p**) memory.

I want to know why? Because apparently, all threads are putting their own values (PFORCES[**ProcID**]...) to the sum of **temp_p** and at the end, that is at the barrier, the results should be same, no matter the order in which threads acquired the locks.

[EDITED]

Also, please note that variables **comp**, **dir** and **mol** are all local variables of the thread and therefore not shared.

Comment: Post the complete *working* code.

Comment: What processor family is this running on? Not all of them make the same cache coherence guarantees. You might have to look into memory fences.

Comment: Nawaz, you can get the code of this from the site http://www-flash.stanford.edu/apps/SPLASH/. The benchmark name is water-nsq.

Comment: spraff, its running on x86. I run it on both single core and dual core, but in both I get the same behavior. Memory fence should be a problem only in multicore, isn't it?

Comment: Kerrek SB, because this code is valid for both C and C++.

Comment: I's also valid for C89, C99, ANSI C, C1X, C++03 C++0x... shall we tag them all? No, only the best fit. C.

Comment: Oww my eyes. This code is in some serious need of refactoring. I can't tell what all is different between the cases. When you have that much near-duplicate code, another function is called for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second try.

I can't check it, but I assume that in `temp_p[H1] += PFORCES[ProcID][mol][dir][H1];` you are adding doubles or floats.

**For floating point types, the order of addition matters!** Floating point addition is not *associative*!

A different thread order means a different addition order. So changes in the outcome are to be expected.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems for some explanation.

Comment: Interesting! Yes temp_p is double. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Exellent Answer! I think this is precisely the reason its not deterministic. Very surprising fact though :)!

Comment: Solve what? The algorithm used is inherently non-deterministic. If that's a problem, the choice of algorithm was incorrect. You could, for example, switch to fixed point math that guarantees order of addition doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you do not show the declaration of the loop variables, like `mol` and `dir`.

Could it be that the are accidently shared between threads?

If so, all kind of race conditions between e.g. one thread's `mol++` and other thread's `[mol % MAXLCKS]` will cause problems.

**UPDATE**: According to the comments below, this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: No, I can confirm you that mol and dir are local variables of the thread, not shared.

Comment: @MetallicPriest Well, without showing the full code, I can't do anything but guessing.